# Jump to Link In W3M

Tags: w3m

The browser `w3m` has an option to turn on link numbers.

<kbd>o</kbd> > 'Display link numbers'

I would like to be able to jump to a particular link by number, i.e. jump to link number 10 by some key shortcut combination.

Is this possible? I have looked carefully and cannot see a way to get this functionality.

I have been able to get the list of all links <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> and then can navigate with the movement keys to the link I am looking for, but it would be nice to jump to a link I can see by somehow typing its number with a key combination.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anything besides doing math in your head "okay, I'm on link number 1, and want to get to 17, so need to type 16 TAB".

Comment: Didn't know about that combination. Its definitely a start, but I'm curious if the functionality is there to jump directly to a number.

Comment: this works in reverse as well... pretty sweet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass a numeric argument to the command `[`. A plain `[` goes to the first link, `42[` goes to the 42nd link.